# Is there a word called this Internet action in English culture?

Tags: word-request

In Chinese Internet forums, people reply a post continuously to make the replies  grow longer is called “盖楼“（make building）。

I wonder is there a word for this action in English?

Comment: Conceptually, Anglophones probably don't normally think in terms of *"growing" a comment thread* - just as if we click a "Like" button in Facebook, or an "Upvote" button on ELL we normally wouldn't try to describe what we just did as "increasing the total positive tally for this item" (we just say we "liked" or "upvoted" it). For a comment thread, we just ***add** [a comment]* to the thread. It would be unusual to specifically reference "lengthening" or "elongating" the thread.

Comment: Note, however, the *noun* which @FumbleFingers uses in his comment. **Thread** is internet usage for a chain of posts on a single topic, often including responses to previous posts. Systems which are more sophisticated than SE's permit sub-threads to branch off from a main thread.

Comment: @Jacob By analogy, when 盖楼 happens in emails what do you call it? When the email gets longer and longer? Doesn't 盖楼 have the meaning building floor by floor?  It is usually referred to as an **email trail**

Comment: I don't know if there's a word for it in English, but it's really just a form of sloppiness or laziness. People should notice that the pasted reply is turning into an ASCII skyscraper and delete those characters before they hit SUBMIT; however, most contributors seem blissfully unaware of the mess being created beneath their own words of wisdom. Great question, though, and I think I might adopt that "building" analogy.

Comment: When a user is 盖楼ing, is he creating bogus replies to make it look as though more people are interested in the thread than really are? Or is he quoting an earlier comment, which quotes another comment, and so on, so that there are many nested quote boxes?

Comment: @user8399 You insight are totally right. Most of time, 盖楼 means adding dull replies, especially post it as a nested quote boxes as your judgement. When you consider one of a replies in the context (with other replies), it will be an interesting reply. That is the sense of 盖楼.

Comment: @Peter  Interesting. In forums, the first reply is called 1st floor, the second 2nd floor and so on. We do have trail, but that is referred to something like 'posted via iphone' or  ' posted from Beijing' things.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for you description, I don't think we have the same notion of **building up**, on some social media, the most recent comment is at the **top**, on others the most recent will be at the bottom (as it is here).  Is the notion of 盖楼 only in one direction or bidirectional? The adjective **padding** is used to describe a **puffing-up to appear larger** and it sounds like if users are just adding posts to make a thread appear more popular it is similar to **padding out**

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a word that matches exactly, but there are a few that are similar.  Since these are neologisms, they are still considered slang and are probably not found in any respected dictionary.

To [**bump**](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/bump) a thread is to reply to it for the purpose of raising it to the top of a list of threads sorted by recent activity, or to prevent its deletion for inactivity.  Lengthening it is not the motive.

**Page widening** was the practice of posting things that would cause a forum page to be formatted incorrectly, forcing people to scroll horizontally to read any of the comments.  This is much less common now that most sites are designed to prevent it.  Examples included posting long "words" that could not be automatically wrapped, such as QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ.  (Notice how Stack Exchange deals with this: it wraps at an arbitrary length, but the programmer didn't bother taking a smaller piece to fill the previous line.  Or maybe that's my browser doing that.  In any case, it does not change the page layout.)

[**Threadjacking**](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/threadjacking), a portmanteau of "thread" and "hijacking", is the practice of changing the subject of a thread.  A related but obscene term is **shitposting**.  Some forms of threadjacking are intended to shift the conversation to something controversial, causing others to post many comments.  Other forms are more transparent.  Often you will see someone post an image like this one, followed by many more like it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can recognized those words in Chinese. bump = 顶(sutain